How to have one jobB from stageB to run only when ALL jobs from stageA are finished

Include details about your goal:

I would like to have one jobB from stageB to run only when ALL jobs from stageA are finished.
stageA  stageB
job01A  jobB
job02A
...
job58A


What did I try:

To achieve this result, I am currently using the keyword "needs", which is working, but the gitlab ci yml is now looking like this:
jobB
  stage: stageB
  needs:
    - job: job01A
    - job: job02A
       ...
    - job: job58A

Either this list, or the array, is long.

Question:

How can I write something that tells jobB to run only when all jobs from stageA are done, without to having explicitly write each one of the jobs?
Something like:
jobB
  stage: stageB
  needs:
    - all jobs from stageA


The pipelines in GitLab are sequential, so if you have an array of stages, each job in a stage will run in parallel (unless explicitly specified) and when all of the jobs in your stage have finished then the next stage will start.
You don't need to add the needs keyword unless there's a need for a more complex relationship. In your example:
stages:
  - StageA
  - StageB

GitLab will execute all jobs from StageA and when those are successful - or failed but with allow_failure - then StageB will commence.
I also found this article which I think you may find interesting to have a read.
